# Склонение названий улиц, переулков

Tags: словообразование

Как правильно писать - по Красному переулку или по переулку Красный

Comment: @Галина1957, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от самого названия. Если переулок называется Красный переулок , то правильно: по Красному переулку. Если сам переулок называется Красный, тогда правильно: по переулку Красный.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: по Красному переулку. Принятый в русском языке стандартный порядок слов такой: согласованное определение, затем определяемое слово: Рощинская улица (ср.: интересная книга). Изменение порядка слов возможно, если нужно упорядочить названия по общему родовому слову (например, в справочнике): переулок такой-то, такой-то и такой-то.

Comment: Тат, а если сам переулок называется: Переулок Красный? Тогда как? Идти по Переулку Красному переулку? Согласитесь,тавтология. Поэтому, как я объяснил выше,все зависит от самого названия.

Comment: Так он в любом случае называется красным. Волжское шоссе - это не улица Волжское шоссе и не шоссе Волжское. Принцип образования микротопонимов - согл. определение + определяемое. Краснозвездный проспект, но проспект Победы. Не бывает переулка Красный, кроме как в алфавитных списках.

Comment: В Википедии:  Красный переулок.  В других местах -  Переулок Красный. Хотя в большинстве случаев - Переулок.Красный.

Comment: Точное наименование: переулок Красный. Выдержка из текста:"Связь с центром города осуществляется по улице Карбышева через узкий тоннель под железнодорожными путями и пешеходные надземные переходы над железнодорожными путями, расположенными в створе переулка Красный..." В этом случае все-таки как правильно - переулка Красный или переулка Красного?

Comment:  Корректно: в створе переулка Красный.

Comment: Грамота: Слова проспект, бульвар, улица принято ставить после согласованных определений: Океанский проспект, Славянский бульвар, Самокатная улица и т. д. Если же названия представляют собой несогласованные определения, то порядок слов иной: улица Льва Толстого, проспект Мира и т. п. - http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_340871 Эта же рекомендация встречается в учебниках по деловому письму. Обратный порядок слов возможен в алфавитных списках и на картах. Но правильное название - Красный переулок. Вообще дискуссий на эту тему много, а источников мало.

Comment: Тат, в том-то и дело, что в интернете встречается два варианта. А по словам автора вопроса,переулок Красный - официальное название

Answer (score 0):

Красный переулок - составное имя собственное, родовое название входит в его состав. Склоняется  как обычное сочетание: Красного переулка, но это В ОБЫЧНОЙ РЕЧИ. Также: на Ленинском проспекте, от Красной площади, в Пожарском переулке.

Несклонение типично для **официально-делового стиля, вообще различных официальных ситуаций:** ДТП произошло на улице Болотная.  Приемный пункт расположен недалеко от улицы Большая Дорогомиловская (объявление). При этом родовое наименование предшествует названию.

ОФИЦИАЛЬНО  ВСЕ ПОДОБНЫЕ НАЗВАНИЯ читаются так: переулок Красный, улица Первомайская, при этом склоняются только родовые наименования. Поэтому переулок имеет две формы: переулок Красный (офиц.) и Красный переулок (неофиц.)

Информация из Практической стилистики современного языка (РАН, 2012)

В приведенном примере стиль как раз официально-деловой, поэтому правильно:"...над железнодорожными путями, расположенными в створе переулка Красный."

Comment: Вера, в данном случае, название:  переулок Красный, а не Красный переулок. Поэтому название не склоняем. Корректно: по переулку Красный.

Comment: Но название официальное: переулок Красный, а не Красный переулок. Есть же разница...

Comment: Правильно так, как в официальном названии.